# Deployment on eApps Glassfish server within ispmanager

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, web-deployment

I want to deploy JAVA web Application on eApps, Glassfish v3.1.1

what's the best way for doing that, I can't access Server domain through myip:4848

> I tried to deploy remotely using netbeans but it failed

Answer (score 0):

- You can deploy applications with the asadmin command: `asadmin deploy /path/to/file.war` The asadmin command-line utility can be found in `/GLASSFISH_HOME/glassfish/bin/`. There a several parameters you can pass to asadmin which are described [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2433/deploy-1.html#SJSASEEREFMANdeploy-1)
- You can manually deploy you applications. You have to copy either the .war file or a folder containing the contents of the .war file to the folder /GLASSFISH_HOME/glassfish/domains/domain1/autodeploy
- **In the normal case** you can deploy .war and .ear files via the Glassfish admin console. Navigate to `http://localhost:4848`, go to Applications, click on Deploy and select the file to deploy (a very detailed description can be found [here](https://support.eapps.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/242/59/cloud-hosting-applications---glassfish-v30#deploying_applications_using_the_glassfish_admin_console))